# How to find all pairs in a list of pairs has overlaps?

Tags: c, algorithm

An array containing a list of 2 number pairs: [n1 n2...]

Each element is `<first second >`.

How do I efficiently find all possible overlaps?

I can think only of the brute force approach with complexity O(n2).

This problem might apply to time overlapping also.

Comment: Do you want to find overlapping intervals?

Comment: @jbr,correct,  yes i do.

Comment: @Keyser, no it isn't, it can be done in O(n * log(n)) time.

Comment: @jbr, how is it possible?

Comment: You pretty much need to loop through each time slot, and then check that particular slot and against every other slot to see if an overlap occurs. You can make it quicker by returning  true as soon as you find an overlap, rather than looping to the end

Comment: @jbr, the maximum number of conflicts is n*(n-1), so the worst case efficiency can't be better (since he wants all possible conflicts).

Comment: See my algorithm bellow, the sorting takes n * log(n), running through the list takes n and profit is O(1), hence all overlaps can be found in n * log(n).

Comment: As others have noted, you probably want to sort on start time. But it won't be as simple as just comparing adjacent time intervals as some have indicated since intervals can span multiple other intervals. You want to go through your array and for each time slot, compare it to every time slot that comes *after* it in the array. So it's a double loop, but the inner loop only spans from the current point forward.

Comment: @mbratch, that's true, my purposed algorithm only detects overlaps.

Comment: You don't need to sort anything. Use a Binary Search Tree (key=first, value=second) and scan over the time (called Event Driven Algorithm) to find the overlapping intervals with each interval. That's the fastest, but you need a library for BST

Comment: @ilius a binary search tree IS sorted. So if his data is not sorted when inserting it into the tree it will be sorted ;-)

Comment: @RedX I'm not sure what you mean by "a sorted tree". Binary Heaps (used in heap sort) are equivalent to an array, but BSTs are not equivalent to an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort time by `start time`.
Then check if next time slot `start time` is higher than current slot `end time`.

```
TimeSlot[] slots;
sort(slots, slots.start_time);
for(i = 0 to (slots.length - 1)){
    if(slots[i].end_time > slots[i + 1].start_time) reportConflict();
}
```

It works in time `O(n log n)` where `n` is number of time slots

If you need to find all conflicted pairs then you need to modify algorithm:

```
TimeSlot[] slots;
sort(slots, slots.start_time);
for(i = 0 to (slots.length - 1)){
    int j = i + 1;
    while(j < (slots.length - 1) and slots[i].end_time > slots[j].start_time){
        reportConflict(i, j);
        ++j;
    }
}
```

It works in time `O((n log n) + c)` where `n` is number of time slots and `c` is number of conflicts

If you need only number of overlaps there is better algorithm using binary search:

```
TimeSlot[] slots;
int overlapsNumber = 0;
sort(slots, slots.start_time);
for(i = 0 to (slots.length - 1)){
    int j = BinarySearch(slots, i);
    overlapsNumber += (j - i);
}

//Finds index j which is the greatest index that slots[j].start_time < slots[i].end_time
int BinarySearch(TimeSlot[] sortedSlots, int pos){
    int b = pos, e = sortedSlots.length - 1;
    int ans = b;
    while(b < e){
        int mid = (e + b) / 2;
        if(sortedSlots[mid].start_time < sortedSlots[pos].end_time){
            ans = mid;
            b = mid + 1;
        } else {
            e = mid - 1;
        }
    }
    return ans;
```

It works in time `O(n log n)`.

Comment: You could use a `for` loop on the inner loop as well and it would be a little more elegant.

Comment: But the c-term is not significant, so it runs i O(n log(n)).

Comment: @jbr It might be if `c` is higher than `n log n`.

Comment: @mbratch In this pseudo language I can't use for, because it would be slower (`O(n^2)`). I like using `for` in pseudo languages only with very simple condition (like `foreach` or `for a to b`).

Comment: @Ari but i wont, as the list of possible overlaps is `\sum_{i=i}^n n - i` so it is exactly n log n.

Comment: I think it is `O(n2)`. Two nested loops iterating through the list, no?

Comment: @jbr No, you can have `(1/2) * (n * (n - 1))` overlaps, which is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @learner You are partialy right, but number of iteration of second loop is lower if there is no overlaps. So if there are about `O(n log n)` overlaps my algorithm works in time `O(n log n). I updated answer with algorihm finding number of overlaps in better time.

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm for doing this is simple enough.

1. Sort your intervals according to start time
2. Go through the list, and check if the current elements end time is greater than the next elements start time.
3. Profit

*Edit*

To detect all overlaps (ie. overlaps spanning multiple intervals) do:

1. Sort you intervals according to start time
2. Check the current elements end time and see if its greater than or equal to the next elements start time.
3. if this is the case mark interval as overlaping, and check the next + 1 elements start time for overlap. Continue this until you reach the end.

Do this for all intervals in the list.

Note that both "algorithms" run in `O(n log n)`. The first one because sorting takes O(n log n) and running through the list takes `O(n)` giving `O(n log n + n) = O(n log n)`. For the second one sorting is still `O(n log n)` and running through the list is now `O((1/2)n^2 + (1/2)n) = O(n^2)` giving `O(n log n + n^2) = O(n^2)`.

*Edit again*
An even better way of doing this, is apparently holding you intervals in [an interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).

Comment: all possible time conflicts?

Comment: Does this take cover the case where a time slot might span multiple subsequent time slots?

Comment: @mbratch no, if you want to check for that, then you need to check all the remaining intervals, but that still only takes n * log(n). Because your search space becomes smaller and small as you progress down the list.

Comment: @jbr, But how will the 2nd part give `nlog(n)` complexity? It should be `n2` (n square) no? Two nested iterations...

Comment: Since the list is sorted, you only need to compare the rest of the list for each n, thus the number of elements you need to compare with as you go through the list gets smaller and smaller. That's where the n log n comes from. So you do two n log n's one after the other.

Comment: @jbr, in selection sort, the selection of the smallest element will be from a sub-array that gets smaller and smaller. The complexity is still `O(n2)`, right?

Comment: @ari yeah sorry, I got the math wrong :) To test for overlaps with the  my suggestion takes O(n^2) as you stated. We have to test n + n -1 + n - 2 + ... + n - n intervals, which is the same as 1 + 2 + ... + n, which is (1/2)n^2 + (1/2)n, which is still O(n^2). But see the last edit about interval tree, for a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Just sort them by `start_time`, then iterate over the list checking that `current.end_time` is not after `next.start_time`.